# Convert char array to number

Tags: c++, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, converting

C++17 have `<charconv>`. However this header does not work on MacOS - It compiles, but can not link. Same header is not present in `MSVS`. The header also missing from my Arm Linux, even my gcc compiler there supports C++17 as well.

Following is a take to convert non terminated char array (e.g. buffer, string_view etc) into signed or unsigned integer.

I probably will use the code in production, once I do some more tests.

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>

namespace impl{
    template<typename T>
    T x10(T a){
        return a * 10;
    }

    inline char digit(char c){
        return c - '0';
    }

    inline bool is_space(char c){
        return c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\r' || c == '\n';
    }

    inline bool is_sign(char c){
        return c == '+' || c == '-';
    }

    inline bool is_digit(char c){
        return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::pair<bool,T> convert_unsigned(const char *c, const char *e){
        T num = 0;

        while(c != e && is_digit(*c)){
            T tmp = x10(num) + digit(*c);

            if (tmp < num)
                return { false, num };

            num = tmp;

            ++c;
        }

        return { true, num };
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::pair<bool,T> convert(const char *c, const char *e, std::true_type /* unsigned */){
        if (c != e && *c == '+')
            ++c;

        return convert_unsigned<T>(c, e);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::pair<bool,T> convert(const char *c, const char *e, std::false_type /* unsigned */){
        using U = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;

        T sign = +1;
        U max  = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

        if (c != e && is_sign(*c)){
            if (*c == '-'){
                sign = -1;
                max  = - (U) std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
            }

            ++c;
        }

        // std::cout << ">>> " << sign << ' ' << max << ' ' << '\n';

        auto [ ok, result ] = convert_unsigned<U>(c, e);

        if (result > max)
            return { false, (T) result };

        if (result == max)
            return { true, (T) result };

        return { ok, sign * (T) result };
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::pair<bool,T> convert(std::string_view const s){
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>);

    return impl::convert<T>(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::is_unsigned<T>{});
}

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void test(const char *s, T correct){
    auto [ok, i] = convert<T>(s);

    if (!ok)
        std::cout << "Err" << '\n';

    std::cout << ( i == correct ? "OK" : "NO") << ' ' << i << '\n';
}

int main(){
    test<uint16_t>  ("-0",              std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::min()    );
    test<uint16_t>  ("65535",           std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()    );
    test<int16_t>   ("+32767",          std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max() );
    test<int16_t>   ("-32768",          std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::min() );
    test<int16_t>   ("+0",              0                   );
    test<int16_t>   ("-0",              0                   );
    test<int16_t>   ("+10",             +10                 );
    test<int16_t>   ("-10",             -10                 );

    test<uint64_t>  ("+0",                      std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::min()    );
    test<uint64_t>  ("+18446744073709551615",   std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()    );
    test<int64_t>   ("+9223372036854775807",    std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() );
    test<int64_t>   ("-9223372036854775808",    std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() );
}
```

Comment: Added some nodes why someone needs these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're missing any documentation or template constraints, but it appears that this code parses only decimal integers, and silently ignores anything after the first non-digit.  There are other departures from the interface of the functions provided in `<charconv>`:

- a leading `+` is accepted and ignored
- <del>not all out-of-range values are detected</del>.

<del>Worse, there's no prevention of signed integer overflow, so there's undefined behaviour on certain inputs.</del>
The avoidance of signed overflow is fragile and could be made clearer to the reader (with suitable `static_assert()` if `requires` isn't palatable, for instance).

I think that writing a function to multiply by 10 is taking functional decomposition a step too far.  I would say the same for subtracting `'0'`, but that could be arguable if it were home for a comment explaining how C++ guarantees that the characters `'0'`..`'9'` are encoded as contiguous values.

There are no tests for any of the failure cases, and all the tests have to be checked externally.  It's better to make `main()` return an error status unless all the tests pass (and diagnostic output should go to `std::clog` or `std::cerr` as appropriate, rather than `std::cout`).

Comment: show me input where i have UB

Comment: `T tmp = x10(num) + digit(*c);` - (...time passes...) ah, that's unreachable with signed `T` - but not obviously so, and it's fragile (signedness passed in a bool).

Comment: >> if it were home for a comment explaining how C++ guarantees that the characters '0'..'9' are encoded as contiguous values.

this is guaranteed from ASCII. also lowest 3 bits is the number.

Comment: I know it's guaranteed by ASCII, but there's nothing that forces C++ implementations to use ASCII.  That's why the comment explaining that C++ _does_ require contiguous digits is valuable.